# How to include a vue component only when required in spa?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-elixir, vue-component

I have made components and saved into different '.vue' files and compiling them  with the help of elixir / gulp and of course browserify.

I am including all the components into one js file,

I want to know that how to reduce the size of "build.js" file that is called each time in every page that contains all the components of the app.

It would be helpful to know such a way to include components only when they required.

> *This question is not related to Vue-router*
>
> *I am new to vue.js*

Comment: Thats the way how it works. You should cache your build.js so that its not called on every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer: http://router.vuejs.org/en/lazy.html

This is supported natively in Webpack.  The example is:

```
require(['./MyComponent.vue'], function (MyComponent) {
  // code here runs after MyComponent.vue is asynchronously loaded.
})
```

If you want to do it with Broswerify, you'll need https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook/blob/master/readme.markdown#partition-bundle .  The code looks like:

```
router.map({
  '/async': {
    component: function (resolve) {
      loadjs(['./MyComponent.vue'], resolve)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: What about code splitting in router ? when mapping the component to the particular route , we can work with one file and all the splitting and usage of components wherever it requires will take care by compilers.

Comment: Yes, you can see in the second example it is in the router file and using the loadjs function to load the component only when it is used.

Comment: @Jeff would you have an example for the browserify partition-bundle config? I can't seem to make it work.